# Testing Django Wagtail - assert that a child of the given Page type can be created under the parent, using the supplied POST data

Tags: django, testing, wagtail

I've defined a custom page model (a blog post) as a child of a parent model (a blog index page) and I want to test that the child can be created under its parent.

The BlogPage and BlogIndexPage models are copied from the wagtail "basic blog" example in the documentation, and works as expected.

I'm trying to follow the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v2.16.1/advanced_topics/testing.html#wagtail.tests.utils.WagtailPageTests.assertCanCreate) but I get the following validation error:

```sh
AssertionError: Validation errors found when creating a cms.blogpage:
E             date:
E               This field is required.
E             intro:
E               This field is required.
E             slug:
E               This field is required.
E             title:
E               This field is required.
```

I suspect that I'm defining my fixture incorrectly, but I am not what the correct form is. Any help is greatly appreciated! Can someone explain why it isn't working?

fixture (apps.cms.tests.fixtures.blogPage.json):

```
[
  {
    "model":"wagtailcore.page",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields":{
      "date":"2022-02-28",
      "intro":"intro to the post...",
      "slug":"slug/",
      "title":"the title",
      "body":"body of the post...",
      "categories":[
        1
      ],
      "content_type": ["cms", "blogpage"],
      "depth": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "cms.blogpage",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {}
  }
]
```

the test class (apps.cms.tests.test_pages.py):

```py
class MyPageTests(WagtailPageTests):
    def setUp(self):
        self.login()
        page = BlogIndexPage(title="Home page", slug="home", path="foo", depth=1)
        page.save()

    def test_create_blog_post(self):
        cwd = Path.cwd()
        root_page = BlogIndexPage.objects.first()
        with open(f"{cwd}/lettergun/apps/cms/tests/fixtures/BlogPage.json") as json_file:
            fixture = json.load(json_file)

        # Assert that a ContentPage can be made here, with this POST data
        self.assertCanCreate(root_page, BlogPage, nested_form_data(fixture))
```

the models (apps.cms.models.py):

```py
class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    template = "blog.html"
    intro = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def get_context(self, request):
        # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
        context = super().get_context(request)
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by("-first_published_at")
        context["blogpages"] = blogpages
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("intro", classname="full")]


class BlogPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey("BlogPage", related_name="tagged_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class BlogPage(Page):
    template = "blog-post.html"

    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField("cms.BlogCategory", blank=True)

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField("intro"),
        index.SearchField("body"),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("date"),
                FieldPanel("tags"),
                FieldPanel("categories", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
            ],
            heading="Blog information",
        ),
        FieldPanel("intro"),
        FieldPanel("body"),
        InlinePanel("gallery_images", label="Gallery images"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to `self.assertCanCreate` is a dictionary of HTTP POST data to be submitted to the 'create page' admin view. This is an entirely different thing to a fixture (which is a representation of the page data as stored in the database), and the data structures are not compatible.

At its simplest, the POST dictionary can just consist of the required fields `date`, `intro`, `slug` and `title`:

```
self.assertCanCreate(root_page, BlogPage, {
    'date': '2022-02-28',
    'intro': "intro to the post...",
    'slug': 'my-blog-page',
    'title': 'My blog page',
})
```

<del>The `nested_form_data` helper is only needed if your test is creating a page with data that's more complex than a flat list of fields - for example, if you wanted your page data to contain some gallery images, you'd need to use it along with the `inline_formset` helper.</del> As you have an InlinePanel on your page, you need to account for that even if you're not passing it any data - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71356332/1853523 for details.

Comment: I've almost got the test to work, based on the demo site from the documentation, but I've run into another problem. I made a separate question out of it. If you have any suggestions I'd love to hear them - https://stackoverflow.com/q/71354745/6553466

Comment: Ah yep - I was wrong about being able to leave out `nested_form_data`, because the inline formset requires some extra housekeeping even if you're not passing it any data. Will answer on the new question and then update this answer...