# Testing Django Wagtail - assert that a child of the given Page type with an image can be created under the parent

Tags: django, testing, wagtail

I've defined a custom page model (a blog post) as a child of a parent model (a blog index page) and I want to test that the child can be created under its parent.

The BlogPage and BlogIndexPage models are copied from the wagtail "basic blog" example in the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#), and works as expected.

I'm trying to follow the documentation but I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Creating a page failed for an unknown reason
```

Through trial and error, I know that the error is caused by including an `InlinePanel` that references another model (`BlogPageGalleryImage`). If I remove this panel from my BlogPost model definition then the test will pass. I don't understand why including the panel causes an error, or how to solve this problem.

Any help is much appreciated!

The problematic line:

```py
...

InlinePanel("gallery_images", label="Gallery images"),

...
```

The models:

```py
class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    template = "blog.html"
    intro = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subpage_types = ["cms.BlogPage", "cms.SimpleBlogPage", "cms.BlogTagIndexPage"]

    def get_context(self, request):
        # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
        context = super().get_context(request)
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by("-first_published_at")
        context["blogpages"] = blogpages
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("intro", classname="full")]


class BlogPage(Page):
    template = "blog-post.html"
    parent_page_types = ["cms.BlogIndexPage"]

    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField("cms.BlogCategory", blank=True)

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField("intro"),
        index.SearchField("body"),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("date"),
                FieldPanel("tags"),
                FieldPanel("categories", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
            ],
            heading="Meta data",
        ),
        FieldPanel("intro"),
        FieldPanel("body"),
        InlinePanel("gallery_images", label="Gallery images"),
    ]


class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="gallery_images")
    image = models.ForeignKey("wagtailimages.Image", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel("image"),
        FieldPanel("caption"),
    ]
```

The test:

```py
class MyPageTests(WagtailPageTests):
    def setUp(self):
        self.login()

        indexPage = BlogIndexPage(title="Home page", path="blog", pk=1, depth=1)
        indexPage.save()

        page = BlogPage(
            title="a blog post", intro="an intro", path="blog/post", depth=2, date="2022-02-23"
        )
        page.save()

        image = Image(height=1, width=1)
        image.save()

        galleryImage = BlogPageGalleryImage(pk=1, page=page, image=image, caption="foo")
        galleryImage.save()

        category = BlogCategory(name="cat1", pk=1)
        category.save()

    def test_create_blog_post(self):
        root_page = BlogIndexPage.objects.first()

        data = {
            "date": datetime.date(2022, 2, 28),
            "title": "the title",
            "intro": "the intro",
            "depth": 2,
        }

        self.assertCanCreate(root_page, BlogPage, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data passed to `assertCanCreate` is a dict of HTTP form submission data to be handled by the 'create' view. When you have an InlinePanel as part of the creation form - even if you're not passing any data into it - there's [a bundle of extra form fields that needs to be present](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform), to tell it how many child forms are being submitted.

You can use the [`inline_formset`](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/testing.html#wagtail.tests.utils.form_data.inline_formset) helper (in conjunction with the [`nested_form_data`](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v2.16.1/advanced_topics/testing.html#wagtail.tests.utils.form_data.nested_form_data) helper which flattens the nested structure into a plain set of form fields) from Wagtail's testing utilities to construct a compatible form submission:

```
from wagtail.tests.utils.form_data import inline_formset, nested_form_data

class MyPageTests(WagtailPageTests):
    # ...

    def test_create_blog_post(self):
        root_page = BlogIndexPage.objects.first()

        data = nested_form_data({
            "date": datetime.date(2022, 2, 28),
            "title": "the title",
            "intro": "the intro",
            "gallery_images": inline_formset([])
        })

        self.assertCanCreate(root_page, BlogPage, data)
```

(You shouldn't need to include `depth` in the form submission, as that's an internal database field used to keep track of the page's position in the page tree - and that's already taken care of in the `assertCanCreate` call as you've specified `root_page` as the parent page.)